# Variadic argument using macros in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

I have 2 platforms which require different library functions but I want to minimize the code required to support them.

C++14 Code :

```
#ifdef PLATFORM2
#define FUNCTION_AUTO unsigned int dmd
#else
#define FUNCTION_AUTO void
#endif

//-- WITHIN THE LIBRARY -- //
double getQuality(FUNCTION_AUTO){
  //Computing
  // return value;
}

//-- MAIN EXECUTABLE -- //
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
#ifdef PLATFORM2
  getQuality(100);
#else
  getQuality();
  #endif
}
```

Is there a better way to define `getQuality(..)` to be common between the 2 platforms without using preprocessor manipulation ?

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach here would be to abstract the platform specific bits into a library and have a consistent abstraction on top of them.

#### platform.h

```
double Quality();
```

#### platform_a.cc

```
#inclue "platform.h"

double Quality() {
  return getQuality();
}
```

#### platform_b.cc

```
#include "platform.h"

double Quality() {
  return getQuality(100);
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include <iostream>
#include "platform.h"

int main() {
  std::cout << Quality();
}
```

Comment: I tried that the first time. The example shown above is one of numerous lib functions and writing top level abstraction for each one of them is not a valid option at them moment